# Detecting misuse of Async/Await: Prevent blocking calls

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, c#-5.0

I am working on a scalable game server system and trying to use await/async excessively for this new project. Up till now I managed to run into several pitfalls. I have figured out most of the solutions and developed a "common practice" of how to write async methods such that those pitfalls are easy to detect & avoid. Unfortunately, the following gives me headaches:

1) Example:

```
async Task<int> RunSqlQuery()
{
    DbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
    ...
    cmd.ExecuteReader();
    ...
}
```

WHOOOM! This is a spoil for several reasons. One, there is an ExecuteReaderAsync(), which would solve the issue. Second, this call will block and stall the internal async framework's worker thread. Not too critical in a desktop environment, but unfortunately, if you have a server with 8000 requests per second, this can seriously harm your performance and it can be terribly hard to track down the precise lines causing the issue.

2) Example:

```
void ThisHurts()
{
    someTask.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}

async Task<int> RunQuery()
{
    ...
    lock(something)
    {
        ThisHurts();
    }
    ...
}
```

I admit this one looks a bit engineered to prove my point but when dealing with lots of code it is a situation that is hard to avoid. Basically calling await in a lock is deadly. Its a catastrophy waiting to happen (literally). There are tons of explanations why, believe them or not, they are true, build something like above and your code will die almost immediately if you have load on your server and the tons of race conditions start chaining together...

So this question is about how to detect those wrong uses of await. Is there some tool like Resharper (which doesn't seem to support most of what I want). I think Microsoft should have tagged all non-blocking methods and force people to either wrap them in an async compatible way or issue a compiler error when trying to call them within async methods. Additionally they could have forced you to use a new "block"-keyword to be added in front of all methods that are not marked non-blocking so that you can stil use them but the shame is immediately displayed.

The main problem I see so far with the async framework is that misuse will only show under heavy load, which is generally terribly hard to debug & trace, because its so much data and the moment you attach a debuigger the problem is gone, because the load is gone. Awesome ;)

Comment: `tagged all non-blocking methods and force people to either wrap them in an async compatible way`  That's impossible.  If you have a blocking method, the only way to make it async is to rewrite it entirely to use non-blocking IO.

Comment: This used to be called a "design mistake", haven't heard it called "catastrophe" before.  I suppose it is if you do TDD at the end of the project.

Comment: “it can be terribly hard to track down the precise lines causing the issue.” I don't think so. Profilers can show you where does your code spend a lot of time. And if you block a lot, you'll see that method there.

Comment: Also, I'm finding it hard to imagine a situation where case 2 would arise naturally, considering that you can't `await` inside a `lock`.

Comment: Um... no. Tagging has nothing to do with making something non-blocking. Its a compiler info, nothing more. Wrapping in async compatible way is whatever way that is, so not impossible at all lol. Well, if the profiler can distinguish between blocking and "await"ing, then yes, but haven't tried it so far. Case two can arise because you can await in a lock. Just not right inside it, but nothing stops APIs you call there from awaiting.

Comment: You can have a look at an existing tool for detecting async/await misuses: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/03448836-db42-46b3-a5c7-5fc5d36a8308

Answer (score 4):

The tooling is still developing around `async` and `await`. At this point (end of 2013), I'd say we have a bit more than minimum viable functionality. I do expect much more in the next couple of years.

The compiler is not the appropriate place to add this functionality; it should transform C# to IL, not attempt to enforce good coding practices. It does do the "easy" checks that can be described as part of the C# *language* (no `await` inside a `lock`, no `async void Main` for console apps, etc).

Possibilities for writing your own checks include: StyleCop / FxCop / VS Code Analysis, NDepend's CQL, a Re# plugin, etc.